# Extra field in manyToMany relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables: `users` and `estates`

A user can be "linked" to multiple estates, and an estate can be "linked" to many users. To handle this manyToMany relationship, I created a "joinTable" estatesUsers in which the primary key is actualy a composite one involving the two foreign keys `userId` and `estateId`.

This was fine until I wanted to add extra fields to this table.

I read that when adding extra fields for such a table, the relationship is not a "manyToMany" anymore but two "oneToMany" relationship instead for each original entities.

My problem is that Doctrine still not consider this table (was the join table) and skip it when I run `php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle yml`

How can I get the command line tool to handle correctly those relationships and generate this new entity (the yml schema files) ?

Extra question: how do I command the tool (inside the yml schema files) to create a repository class for each entity before running `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle` ?

Thank you !

Comment: can you put your entities class so we can help you

Comment: I actually do not have any entity classes. All I have is the mysql database.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you don't have a User or Estate entity and yet things were working fine? Strange.  In any event, when you add properties to a join table then you will indeed end up with two OneToMany relations and you will need an entity for the join table.  Maybe post your database schema editing out all the irrelevant columns.

Comment: I just started a new application from scratch. I'm working on the model phase. I built the database with phpmyadmin and I was about to export it into the doctrine mapping system. Does it make sense ? I'm now stuck on trying to import the model with the Doctrine console commands ...